# Strip str between last 2 instances of common character

Tags: python, string

I have many different strings (which are files) that look like this:

```
20201225_00_ec_op_2m_temp_24hdelta_argentinacorn_timeseries.nc
20201225_00_ec_op_2m_temp_chinawheat_timeseries.nc
20201225_00_ec_op_snowfall_romaniawheat_timeseries.nc
```

And many more. I want to be able to loop through all of these files and store their file path in a dictionary. To do that, I want the key to be the text that is between the last two instances of an underscore. For example, if this was the file `20201225_00_ec_op_2m_temp_24hdelta_argentinacorn_timeseries.nc`, then the dict would be

`{'argentinacorn': path/to/file/20201225_00_ec_op_2m_temp_24hdelta_argentinacorn_timeseries.nc`

How can I loop through and do this pythonically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexes to extract the key from the strings like this:

```
import re
input_string = "20201225_00_ec_op_2m_temp_24hdelta_argentinacorn_timeseries.nc"
dict_key = re.findall(".*_(.+)_[^_]+", input_string)[0]
```

gives

```
'argentinacorn'
```

Or with just a simple `split`:

```
dict_key = input_string.split("_")[-2]
```

Regarding file names, you can get the list from current working directory like this:

```
import os
file_names = os.listdir()
```

You can just loop through this list and apply the split/regex as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

A simple split and pick:

```
parts = "20201225_00_ec_op_2m_temp_24hdelta_argentinacorn_timeseries.nc".split("_")
key = parts[-2:-1]
```